# MediaWiki 1.18.3/1.19.0 : Namespaces restrictions

Tags: permissions, namespaces, mediawiki

I try to create some permissions on my MediaWiki. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access), but it didn't work...

I try to create a Staff group which have permission to read, edit, create and delete pages into the Staff namespace.
Classic users should not see all pages in this namespace.

Here is the LocalSettings.php file :

```
# Namespaces
define('NS_STAFF', 103);
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_STAFF] = 'Staff';

# Groups
define('G_STAFF', 'Staff');

# Default Group Rights
    # Anonyms
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['create'] = false;
    # User
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['read'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['create'] = false;
    # Staff
$wgGroupPermissions[G_STAFF]['read'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions[G_STAFF]['edit'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions[G_STAFF]['create'] = true;

# Groups Rights
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_STAFF] = array(G_STAFF);
```

Could explain me what i'm doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

I upgraded my Mediawiki to version 1.19.0.
The pages into the namespace "Staff" are still visible for the user group but not editable.

How to block the access to pages into a specific namespace ?

Here is the LocalSettings.php file :

```
#Groups
define('G_PROGRAMMER', 'Programmer');
define('G_ADMIN_SYSTEM', 'AdminSystem');
define('G_DESIGNER', 'Designer');
define('G_STAFF', 'Staff');

# Default Group Rights
    # Anonyms
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['create'] = false;
    # User
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['read'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['create'] = false;
    # Staff
$wgGroupPermissions[G_STAFF]['read'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions[G_STAFF]['edit'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions[G_STAFF]['create'] = true;

# Groups Rights
$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_STAFF] = array('staff-edit');
$wgGroupPermissions[G_STAFF]['staff-edit'] = true;
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to happen and what's actually happening?

Comment: Actually, pages into the namespace "Staff" are visible for everyone but editable just by the Staff group.

Is it possible to block the access of staff pages for simple users ? Or need I an extension ?

Comment: I think this should be migrated to ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Extension:Lockdown](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLockdown), however be advised that MediaWiki architecturally does not guarantee 100% secure partial read restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the $wgNamespaceProtection allows to prevent editing (and only editing) of a custom namespace (see [documentation about $wgNamespaceProtection](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual_talk%3a%24wgNamespaceProtection)).

To prevent reading of a custom namespace an extension is needed.

I'll try [Lockdown](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLockdown).