# How to restrict read permission of a namespace in mediawiki

Tags: permissions, mediawiki, wiki

Is there any way to  restrict everyone's read permission of a particular **namespace** in mediawiki ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mediawiki 1.18.3/1.19.0 : Namespaces restrictions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535524/mediawiki-1-18-3-1-19-0-namespaces-restrictions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restricting read permissions granularly is [tricky in MediaWiki, but possible](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Security_issues_with_authorization_extensions). If you have only one namespace and one group ("everyone") to restrict, the [Lockdown extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown) will do. Download the extension, then in your configuration:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/Lockdown/Lockdown.php";
$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[NS_PROJECT]['read'] = array('user');
$wgNonincludableNamespaces[] = NS_PROJECT;
```

(for the "Project:" namespace).